# Button Click Inside UpdatePanel loses TextBox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, webforms

I have a button inside of nested UpdatePanels. The button does not cause it's click event to occur server side unless I give it the option `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` but when I do so it loses the TextBox value inside of the same, nested, UpdatePanel. Everything displays properly on the screen but I cannot call the function AND get the TextBox text.

Example:

```
<UpdatePanel>
    <MultiView>
        <UpdatePanel>
            <MultiView>
                <TextBox>
                <Button>
```

Comment: Did this text box have EnableViewState=true ?

Comment: Yes it does, as does the button.

Comment: Then maybe on code behind you change that text... debug your code behind to see if that is the issue.

Comment: The only thing that interacts with the UpdatePanels, MultiViews, or TextBox is the button click event. If I turn UseSubmitBehavior to false it will enter the function but as soon as it does the TextBox has no value, though it does find it.